# Помогите разобраться!

Tags: антонимы

1. Скажите, пожалуйста,есть ли к слову "Бог" антонимы, и если да,то какие?
2. Какое слово является антонимом к слову "Истина" и "Правда"?
3. Есть ли различия между словами "Истина" и "Правда"?

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 3):

1. Чёрт, дьявол, сатана, бес
2. истина - заблуждение, правда - ложь

Истина - объективное понятие (то, какие факты имели место; как устроен мир и т.д.). Правда - субъективное понятие, заключается в суждении об истинности чего-либо. В бытовом смысле говорят преимущественно о "правде". Об истине рассуждают больше в научном, религиозном или криминалистическом смысле.

-- Правда ли, что Земля вращается? - Да, это доказанная истина.

-- Неужели Мориарти убил его? - Это неправда, но мы установим истину.

Смысловым антонимом истины является ошибочное представление о чём-либо, антонимом правды является утверждение, не соответствующее действительности.

Answer (score 3):

Правда - соответствие излагаемой информации действительным фактам. Ложь -  преднамеренное искажение этой информации.

Истина - правильное, настоящее, подлинное суждение на различные темы. Заблуждение - неправильное суждение,убеждение.

Правда и истина могут являться синонимами в общеразговорной речи, но истина - это более широкое понятие, оно характерно для книжной речи, философской тематики,что видно из следующей цитаты:

"Вода в сосуде прозрачна. Вода в море — темна. У маленьких истин есть ясные слова; у великой Истины — великое безмолвие" (Р. Тагор).

Но слово "правда"   также можно встретить в философских изречениях:

"Правда всегда побеждает. Ибо то, что побеждает, всегда оказывается правдой".

"Нет правды на земле, но правды нет и выше" (А.Пушкин).

Comment: <"Нет правды на земле, но правды нет и выше" (А.Пушкин).> Написано, знамо, Пушкиным, но это слова пушкинского персонажа - Сальери. Сам А.С. на темы теософии выражался более определенно.

Answer (score 2):

1. В зависимости от религиозных взглядов. В христианстве полного антонима слову "Бог" нет, так как Сатана не равновелик Богу. Однако на обыденном уровне антонимами могут быть "Сатана", "дьявол", "Люцифер" и пр.
2. Истина - ложь, заблуждение, правда.
   Правда - ложь, выдумка, истина
3. Истина - это философская категория, обозначающая объективную правду. В зависимости от философского и/или религиозного течения, истиной или обладает только Бог "Абсолютный дух", или это неосуществимый идеал. Правда - это истинное, относительно субъекта высказывание. В отличии от истины, которая одна на всех, правда у каждого своя.

Answer (score 2):

Антоним к слову бог/Бог целиком зависит от контекста. Примеры:

1. Он просто бог программирования. А я - обычный дилетант. (профессионализм)
2. Ты не Бог, ты просто человек/смертный/раб. (уровень возможностей)
3. Это не Бог тебе нашептывает эти мысли, а Сатана/Дьявол/Люцифер! (религия)
4. Внизу животные, посередине человек, а наверху - Бог! (троичная схема жизни, мистика, религия)
5. Бог - все, пустота - ничто. (вопросы философии)

"Чистого" же антонима к слову Бог как к концепции, наверное, не существует (такого как черный/белый, день/ночь и т.п.). Но, как вы видите, мы можем подбирать антонимы к каким-то отдельным его качествам или ролям. При этом даже самый расхожий антоним (Сатана/Дьявол) очень сильно прицеплен к монотеизму и в частности к Христианству. А в контексте политеизма не будет иметь такого смысла. Более того, дьявол не является противоположностью Богу и в христианстве, потому как он далеко не равен Богу. Это не злобог из дуалистических религий. Но тут мы рискуем уже сильно отклониться от вопросов лингвистики. :)